# JQuery Dialog remove status image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have password form in a jQuery dialog. Once form is submitted, I need to remove that image, but that doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone tell me how to do this please?

This is dialog's HTML:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Retrieve it</span>
</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
</button>
</div>
<img id="password-status" class="progressStatus" title="Status" alt="Status" src="/Content/alert/progress.gif" style="">
</div>
```

This is what I am doing:

```
$("#password-status").remove().fadeOut();
```

Another attempt:

```
 $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").remove($("#password-status").fadeOut());
```

Comment: Do You really want to remove it or just hide it? If just wanna hide, do a $('#yourID').toggle(); it gives a kind of fade out effect.

Comment: @ricardordz , your solution is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using [an HTML form submit](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), the page will be refreshed so you won't have to *remove* it.  Make your server-side code just not add it when viewing the page with a form submit.  You'll do this in PHP or ASP code (or whatever server side technology you're using).

If you're using AJAX instead of an HTML form, try adding `id` to each button, and binding the click event via jQuery.

Here's [a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/NWYkN/).

Your HTML modified to add those `id`s:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button id="retrieve-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="ui-button-text">Retrieve it</span>
    </button>
    <button id="cancel-button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <img id="password-status" class="progressStatus" title="Status" alt="Status"
       src="/Content/alert/progress.gif">
</div>
```

JS to disable the image on click:

```
$("#retrieve-button").click(function() {
    // Todo: Add submit https AJAX call here, and bind success to removeImages.
    // For now, we'll just call it directly
    removeImages();
});

function removeImages() {
    $("#password-status").remove().fadeOut();
}
```